# Ivy dependency error with hive-jdbc

Tags: java, jdbc, ant, hive, ivy

Following is my ivy file :

```
<configurations>
    <conf name="default" description="Default configuration"/>
    <conf name="runtime" description="The configuration needed for runtime" extends="default"/>
    <conf name="compile" description="The configuration needed to compile" extends="default"/>
    <conf name="test" description="The configuration needed to run the tests" extends="compile"/> 
    <conf name="sources" description="Source files configuration"/>
</configurations>
<dependencies>
    <dependency org="hibernate" name="hibernate" rev="3.5.3" conf="compile,runtime -> default"/>

    <dependency org="org.apache.hive" name="hive-jdbc" rev="2.0.0" conf="compile,runtime -> default">
        <artifact name="hive-jdbc" ext="jar"/>
        <exclude module="mail" />
        <exclude module="libthrift" />
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

When connecting to hive I am getting the following error :

> java.lang.IncompatibleClassChangeError: class org.apache.hive.service.cli.thrift.TCLIService$Client has interface org.apache.thrift.TServiceClient as super class

Can anyone please let me know what is the problem?

Comment: Unable to reproduce. Furthermore I discovered that the hibernate dependency could not be found suggesting you are not retrieving from the upstream community repositories. I suggest considering the following: http://search.maven.org/#artifactdetails%7Corg.hibernate%7Chibernate-core%7C3.5.3-Final%7Cjar

Comment: Duplicate of https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/HIVE-2935  Read the thread in detail where it discuss problem with dependencies.

Comment: I read the thread which is why I used the <exclude module = "libthrift"> in the hive dependency but that doesn't solve the problem. I still get the same error. Could you please let me know if that's what has to be done or something else? Thanks a lot! @MarkO'Connor